# Sum of Numbers in string in R separated by Vertical Bar

Tags: r, regex, sum

I have a string having value as given below separated by vertical bar.

```
String1 <- "5|10|25|25|10|10|10|5"
String2 <- "5|10|25|25"
```

Is there any Direct Function to get the sum of the numbers in string ,
in this case it Should be 100 for Srting1 and 65 for string2,and I have a character vector of such.

```
>chk
                chk
1 5|10|25|25|10|10|10|5
2       5|55|20|5|5|5|5
3                     6
4        Not Available
> sum(scan(text=gsub("\\Not Available\\b", "NA", chk$chk), sep="|", what = numeric(), quiet=TRUE), na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 206
```

As it Should be

```
 [1]100 100 6 NA
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can do a `scan` and then `sum`

```
sum(scan(text=String1, sep="|", what = numeric(), quiet=TRUE))
```

For multiple vectors, place it in a `list` and do the same operation

```
sapply(mget(paste0("String", 1:2)), function(x) 
        sum(scan(text=x, sep="|", what=numeric(), quiet=TRUE)))
# String1 String2 
#    100      65
```

---

Another option is `eval(parse(` (not recommended though) after replacing the `|` with `+`

```
eval(parse(text=gsub("[|]", "+", String1)))
#[1] 100
```

Or as @thelatemail mentioned in the comments, assign (`<-`) the `|` to `+` and then do the `eval(parse(`..

```
`|` <- `+`
eval(parse(text=String1))
#[1] 100
```

---

If we have a `data.frame` column with strings, then it may be better to split by `|` to a `list` of `vector`s, convert the `vector`s to `numeric` (all the non-numeric elements coerce to `NA` with a friendly warning), get the `sum` with `na.rm=TRUE`

```
sapply(strsplit(as.character(chk$chk), "[|]"), 
     function(x) sum(as.numeric(x), na.rm=TRUE))
#[1] 100 100   6   0
```

NOTE: The `as.character` is not needed if the 'chk' column is already a `character` class

Otherwise, if we are using `scan` or `eval(parse`, it should be done for each element.

Comment: Thanks @akrun,Preety Fast :)

Comment: Why not really abuse `eval(parse...`?  - `\`|\` <- \`+\`; eval(parse(text=String1))` :-)

Comment: @thelatemail I haven't thought to that depths, but looks very interesting.

Comment: For the Code
    sum(scan(text=String1, sep="|", what = numeric(), quiet=TRUE))
In place of String1 can column be used ? Like Datset$Column

Comment: @Shivpe_R It can be used, make sure that the column is `character` class and not `factor`.  If it is `factor`, convert to `character` ie. `sum(scan(text= as.character(Dataset$Column)..`

Comment: Column Class is  Character Which contains NA's and Text like "Not Avialable" too

Comment: @Shivpe_R  In that case replace the `Not Available` with `NA` and then use the `na.rm = TRUE` in `sum` i.e. `sum(scan(text=gsub("\\bNot Available\\b", "NA", String1), sep="|", what = numeric(), quiet=TRUE), na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: This Will give the sum of whole column as Grand Total like 165 in the above case. which is not true.

Comment: @Shivpe_R I am not getting that `String1 <- "5|10|25|25|10|10|NA|10|Not Available|5";sum(scan(text=gsub("\\bNot Available\\b", "NA", String1), sep="|", what = numeric(), quiet=TRUE), na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 100`, and `5 + 10 + 25 + 25 + 10 + 10 + 10 +5 #[1] 100`

Comment: @Shivpe_R You have to do this on each element in your new dataset i.e. `apply(chk, 1, FUN = function(x) sum(scan(text=gsub...`

Comment: This Works,Thanks

Answer (score 2):

We can extract all the numbers from the string and then `sum` over it

```
library(stringr)
sum(as.numeric(unlist(str_match_all(String1, "[0-9]+"))))
#[1] 100

sum(as.numeric(unlist(str_match_all(String2, "[0-9]+"))))
#[1] 65
```

For multiple vectors we can keep it in a list

```
sapply(list(String1, String2), function(x) 
                                  sum(as.numeric(unlist(str_match_all(x, "[0-9]+")))))
#[1] 100  65
```